# matplotlib fill_between not filling properly

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two curves that I get from the columns of a dataframe, and I am trying to fill_between them.

```py
plt.plot(cv_Bi40_1['control/V'][323:], cv_Bi40_1['<I>/mA'][323:], color = 'purple')
plt.plot(cv_Bi40_2['control/V'][0:1004], cv_Bi40_2['<I>/mA'][0:1004], color = 'red')

x = list(cv_Bi40_1['control/V'][323:])
y1 = list(cv_Bi40_2['<I>/mA'][0:1004])
y2 = list(cv_Bi40_1['<I>/mA'][323:])

plt.fill_between(x, y2, y1)
```

[image: fill_between not working]

What could be causing the function to not fill_between properly?

Comment: What I think the problem is might be the fact that your x-series are not equivalent. You are using the ```cv_Bi40_1``` slice for your first plot and the ```cv_Bi40_2``` slice for your second plot. As I can see a discontinuity at x=0.66, I think your curves are ill-defined which messes up your ```fill_between```, which presumes an equal x-series.

Comment: Makes sense... any ways to get around that? I've tried using `fill`, and that gives me no luck either

Comment: Two suggestions: use fill_between twice for each section of the graph, or combine the slices to create a single x,y1,y2 series which you have to both plot and fill just once.